# MySQL Union returns BLOB

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to union 2 tables which have the same fields (with the same varchar size/int size etc)

But in the browser I get blobs...

```
select * from
(
select * from (
SELECT media.id,ifnull(wasRead,0) as wasRead
,teamid,newsDate,itemid
,var1,var2,var3,var4,title,content
,ifnull(optionSel,0) as optionSel,0 as itemType
FROM media
left join mediaList on mediaList.id = media.itemId
where teamid = '1') as media

union all

select * from (
select managerNews.id,ifnull(wasRead,0) as wasRead
,teamid,newsDate,itemid
,var1,var2,var3,var4,title,content
,ifnull(optionSel,0) as optionSel,0 as itemType
from managerNews
left join managerNewsList on managerNewsList.id = managerNews.itemId
where teamid = 1) as managerNews
) as merged

order by newsDate desc
limit 50
```

I just don't know what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post what you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the browser"? Are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: Instead of "player:36" I get 706C617965723A3136

Comment: And when i run it on Workbench I get the values I need, like normal text, but when I use it on my website I get the blobs. The workbench doesn't show me any BLOB...

Comment: By the way, I just noticed that the only field that returns as BLOB (or whatever it is) is "var1"
I'm trying to figure out why is that, this field is not different from the others... :S

Comment: Another thing - when I run this query at phpMyAdmin, it returns var1 & content fields as blobs. ( "[BLOB - 9B]" )

Answer (score 0):

Well, had a different collation on that row. So weird, I saw that mistakenly but it's finally solved.

Thanks :-)